# Angular call component from one module to another module

Tags: angular, module, components

I have two modules gridusers module and users module.The grid module will list the all users in data table , when I click the action item edit it will open a popup to edit the users. With the edit user, I'm trying to create a component in user module. When I try to use that edit user component in gridusers module, I'm getting an error:

> template parse error and Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse
>   errors: 'app-edit-user' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-edit-user' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-edit-user' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.

Any help on this?

```
gridmodule
  -- gridmodule.ts
  -- gridcomponent.ts
  -- gridcomponent.html
  -- gridcomponent.scss

usermodule
  -- usermodule.ts
  -- usercomponent.ts
  -- usercomponent.html
  -- editusercomponent.ts
  -- editusercomponent.html
  -- usercomponent.scss
  -- editusercomponent.scss
```

**editusercomponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-user',
  templateUrl: './editusercomponent.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editusercomponent.scss']
})
export class editusercomponent{
  title = 'edit user';
}
```

**gridmodule.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        editusercomponent
    ],
    imports: [
        .-----
    ],
})
```

Comment: please provide any code, and I think the problem is you didn't declare your component in your module.

Comment: @AmayaSan: Added my sample code

Comment: You need Shared Module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@ngModule's` exports array. Every element defined in the `declarations` array is private by default. you should only export whatever the other modules in our application need to perform its job.

**usermodule.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    @NgModule({
       imports:[CommonModule],
        declarations: [
            editusercomponent
        ],
       exports:[ editusercomponent]
    })
```

**gridmodule.ts**
Regsiter usermodule in gridmodule's `imports` array

```
 import { UserModule } from '../user-module/user.module';
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
       UserModule
      ],
      declarations: [],
      bootstrap: []
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want other modules to use your component you have to export it in your module

Try this

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        editusercomponent
    ],
    imports: [
        .-----
    ],
    exports: [editusercomponent]
})
```